# How to make animation on filter/toggle effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make animation for my search engine that I have but I have no idea how to do so.

I have this in my HTML

```
<div id="companyRoster" class="companyRoster container">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee">
            <img src="images/j-doe.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle padding-0" data-toggle="popover" title="John Doe" data-placement="bottom" data-content='<b>Position:</b> Team Leader Integration Services <br> <b>Department:</b> IT <br> <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:j.doe@aaa.aa">j.doe@aaa.aa</a> <br> <b>Skype:</b> <a href="skype:j.doe?userinfo">j.doe</a>'><i hidden>J Doe Team Leader Integration Services</i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee">
            <img src="images/john-d.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle padding-0" data-toggle="popover" title="John Doe" data-placement="bottom" data-content='<b>Position:</b> Software Engineer <br> <b>Department:</b> IT <br> <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:john.d@aaa.aa">john.d@aaa.aa</a> <br> <b>Skype:</b> <a href="skype:john.d?userinfo">john.d</a>'><i hidden>John D Software Engineer</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The search engine itself is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchField").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $(".employee").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

It is working like a charm right now, but I want to add animation when all others disappear and when they appear again (something like fade in/fade out).

Current look:
[image: current look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for. Isotope is widely use and easy to 
`link:` https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu

There are other examples on how to use Isotope. `link:`
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I will stick with the one provided by @Α. Papadakis

Comment: Actually, I just tested Isotope as well - great one! I will be using it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could "play" with visibility and opacity. Add **.show** class in every employee.  In every keyup event in the search field remove the class **show** from all employees and then add it only to the employees that are going to be shown. Also use a setTimeout function to achieve the fade effect. Check the updated jsfiddle bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#searchField").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".employee").removeClass("show");

  setTimeout(function() {
   $(".employee").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1).addClass("show");
   });
  },300);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>emerchantpay - Company Roster</title>

 <style type="text/css">

 .employee {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
 }

 .employee.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 }

 .employee > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
 }

</style>
</head>

<body>

 <form class="form-inline mx-auto">
  <button class="home btn btn-outline-success btn-margin-right active" type="button">Company Roster</button>
  <button class="room btn btn-outline-success btn-margin-right" type="button">Room Location</button>
  <button class="responsibilities btn btn-outline-success btn-margin-right" type="button">App Responsibilities</button>
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control col-8" placeholder="Search" aria-label="search" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon" id="searchField">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon"><i class="material-icons">search</i></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>

 <div id="companyRoster" class="companyRoster container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show">
    <div>

    </div>
    <i hidden>J Doe Team Leader Integration Services</i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show ">
    <div>

    </div>      <i hidden>J Doe Team Leader Integration Services</i>      
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show">
    <div>

    </div>  <i hidden>J Doe Team Leader Integration Services</i>         
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-2">
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show">
    <div>

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show">
    <div>

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-6 employee show">
    <div>

    </div>            
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just tried this and transition-delay as well - both did not work.
I believe it has some thing to do with the javascript search engine that I written. Edit: I did not write it, I took it from stack overflow.

Comment: Here is the full code - it cannot run in jsfiddle as my files are local, but at least you can take a look at the full code - https://jsfiddle.net/vmvelev/abs3v1yj/

Comment: I think it worked finally. I updated the jsfiddle, please check!

Comment: This is really great! I will think of a way to make it "not refreshing" when only 1 result is shown. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a fade effect you can use fadeToggle() jquery function

Comment: When using this, the search engine stops working :( 
https://i.imgur.com/pxsBBFN.gif